# Which organization maintain those code -> /home/BR6485EAC/linux-2.6.36.x/net/ipv4/netfilter

Tags: kernel, iptables, netfilter

Which organization maintain those code  ->  /home/BR6485EAC/linux-2.6.36.x/net/ipv4/netfilter/

for example, **-m weburl** match kernel code ipt_weburl.c. Who maintain ipt_weburl.c or others(nf_nat_rtsp.c  nf_nat_ipsec.c...etc)

I can't find code in www.netfilter.org and www.kernel.org.

Maybe someone could help me~
Thanks a lot~

Comment: Near the top of the file should be a contact for the original author of the file. For example, in the copies of **ipt_weburl.c** that I can find it credits Eric Bishop as the main author. He would likely also be the one to maintain the code itself. Other files will likely have similar comments.

Comment: Thanks for your reply~